# Can I pass a Custom Metadata Type record from a Flow into a LWC as an input property?

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow

I'm trying to pass a Custom Metadata Type record (Record_Type__mdt) into a Lightning Web Component (LWC) from a Flow. In my LWC I have:

```
<targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
        <property name="opportunityRecordTypeMetadata" type="@salesforce/schema/Record_Type__mdt" label="Opportunity RecordType Metadata" role="inputOnly"/>
        <property name="opportunityRecord" type="@salesforce/schema/Opportunity" label="Opportunity Record"/>
        <property name="selectedStageChoice" type="String" label="Selected Stage Choice" role="outputOnly"/>
    </targetConfig>
</targetConfigs>
```

The Opportunity and String type properties work fine, but the Custom Metadata Type record doesn't show as either an input or output property in the Flow.

I'm guessing this is just a current restriction in the Flow/LWC interface? Or is there a workaround?

Comment: Still the same behaviour mid 2021. Metadata type string is accepted as a valid type but the property is not available in the flow.

Comment: Anyone found solution to this?? Only workaround I've found is to use a customProperty, but user have to choose correct type.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/use-flow-custom-property-editor-sobject-lwc-example.html